# How to implement a sequence of numbers, each consecutive pair adds to 4?

Tags: alloy

I have a sequence (seq) of numbers.

I want the addition of each consecutive pair of numbers to equal 4.

Below is my attempt at implementing this. But, it is wrong. The Alloy Analyzer showed me it's wrong, by generating this instance:

```
2, 2, -2, 4
```

The first pair adds to 4. (2 + 2 = 4)

The second pair does not. (2 + -2 = 0)

What is the correct way to implement this? Note: I need to use sequences (`seq`), so please don't change the signature or its field. I am hoping that you can show me the correct way to express the `fact`. Or, tell me that it's impossible to implement given the use of `seq`.

```
one sig Test {
    numbers: seq Int
}

fact {
    all disj n, n': Test.numbers.elems { 
        (plus[Test.numbers.idxOf[n], 1] = Test.numbers.idxOf[n']) =>
            plus[n, n'] = 4
    }
}

run {#Test.numbers.indsOf[2] > 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain why your fact is incorrect, consider the following counterexample: the `Test.numbers` sequence is `2, 2, 2, 4`.

In that counterexample:

- `Test.numbers.elems` evaluates to `2, 4`
- `Test.numbers.idxOf[2]` is `0` (the first index of element `2`)
- `Test.numbers.idxOf[4]` is `3`
- there are no two disjoint `n` and `n'` in `Test.numbers.elems` (i.e., `{2, 4}`) such that `plus[Test.numbers.idxOf[n], 1] = Test.numbers.idxOf[n']` so the fact trivially holds.

The following fact should express your desired property correctly:

```
fact {
    all i: Test.numbers.inds - (#Test.numbers).prev | 
      plus[Test.numbers[i], Test.numbers[i.next]] = 4
}
```

- `mySeq.inds` evaluates to indexes of the sequence `mySeq`
- `i.next` evaluates to `i + 1`
- `i.prev` evaluates to `i - 1`

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much Aleksandar. Brilliant explanation!